# Not access Google Colab to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, permission-denied, tpu

I am working in a notebook of Google Colab. I get the dataset from Kaggle and save it to the '/content' path. This dataset contains images to make a deep learning model.

Then, on Google Cloud Platform, I have created a bucket to store said dataset, in the service Cloud Storage. It is uploaded without problems in the bucket, since I have verified it go.

The problem is the following, I connect to Google Colab with the TPU accelerator, and with this code:

```
AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

IMAGE_SIZE = [256, 256]
imSize = 256

BATCH_SIZE = 16 * tpu_strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

validation_split = 0.19
filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(gcs_pattern)
split = len(filenames) - int(len(filenames) * validation_split)
train_fns = filenames[:split]
validation_fns = filenames[split:]


def read_labeled_tfrecord(example):
    features = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), # tf.string means bytestring
        "target": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),  # shape [] means single element
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, features)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(example['image'], channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0  # convert image to floats in [0, 1] range
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]) # explicit size needed for TPU
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [imSize,imSize])
    label = tf.cast(example['target'], tf.int32)
    return image, label 

def read_unlabeled_tfrecord(example):
    u_features = {
        "image": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), # tf.string means bytestring
        "image_name": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),  # shape [] means single element
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, u_features)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(example['image'], channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0  # convert image to floats in [0, 1] range
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]) # explicit size needed for TPU
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [imSize,imSize])
    idnum = example['image_name']
    return image, idnum # returns a dataset of image(s)

def data_augment(image, label):
    #original_image = image
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
    image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.01)
    image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 0.7, 1.3)
    image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, 0.8, 1.2)
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, 0.2)
    return image, label 

def load_dataset(filenames, labeled=True):
    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTO) # automatically interleaves reads from multiple files
    dataset = dataset.with_options(ignore_order) # uses data as soon as it streams in, rather than in its original order
    dataset = dataset.map(read_labeled_tfrecord if labeled else read_unlabeled_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    # returns a dataset of (image, label) pairs if labeled=True or (image, id) pairs if labeled=False
    return dataset

def get_training_dataset():
    dataset = load_dataset(train_fns, labeled=True)
    dataset = dataset.map(data_augment, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    dataset = dataset.repeat() # the training dataset must repeat for several epochs
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO) # prefetch next batch while training (autotune prefetch buffer size)
    return dataset

training_dataset = get_training_dataset()
validation_dataset = load_dataset(validation_fns).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(AUTO)
```

I read all the information uploaded in the GCP and get training and validation datasets.

So, when I code this:

```
CLASSES = ['Bening', 'Malignant']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def display_one_flower(image, title, subplot, color):
  plt.subplot(subplot)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.imshow(image)
  plt.title(title, fontsize=16, color=color)
  
# If model is provided, use it to generate predictions.
def display_nine_flowers(images, titles, title_colors=None):
  subplot = 331
  plt.figure(figsize=(13,13))
  for i in range(9):
    color = 'black' if title_colors is None else title_colors[i]
    display_one_flower(images[i], titles[i], 331+i, color)
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
  plt.show()

def get_dataset_iterator(dataset, n_examples):
  return dataset.unbatch().batch(n_examples).as_numpy_iterator()

training_viz_iterator = get_dataset_iterator(training_dataset, 9)
```

And this:

```
# Re-run this cell to show a new batch of images
images, classes = next(training_viz_iterator)
class_idxs = np.argmax(classes, axis=-1) # transform from one-hot array to class number
labels = [CLASSES[idx] for idx in class_idxs]
display_nine_flowers(images, labels)
```

I get this error:

```
PermissionDeniedError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "XX@cloud-tpu.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "XX@cloud-tpu.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not '
     when reading metadata of gs://name_bucket/Dataset
```

How can I fix it? It is pretty serious for me..